# How can I use custom Look&Feel theme in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, themes

It is possible to download a L&F java theme and use it in netbeans ?

for example use one of these themes:
http://geeknizer.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10/

I tried this instructions but it looks old:
http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2008/05/how-to-customize-netbeans-look-and-feel.html

Using netBeans 7.2

UPDATE:

this command seems work:
`./netbeans --cp:p /home/fra/Desktop/jgoodies-looks-2.4.2/jgoodies-looks-2.4.2.jar --cp:p /home/fra/Desktop/jgoodies-looks-2.4.2/lib/jgoodies-common-1.2.1.jar --laf com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel`

Comment: Did you get any error message or exception while tried that link?

Comment: I have tried this 
`./netbeans --cp:p /home/fra/Desktop/jgoodies-looks-2.4.2/jgoodies-looks-2.4.2.jar --laf Plastic3DLookAndFeel` 

    but I got error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jgoodies/common/base/SystemUtils`

Comment: Have you installed full Netbeans?

Comment: That should actually work. Lets see...

Comment: Any progress buddy, @Francesco

Comment: I have tried with Substance, Napkin, Synthetica, TinyLaF, JGoodies Plastic. But I can make work only GGoodies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a flag. You can check [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomLaf) for more info. And to change to some predefined LaF:

#### Available Themes

- **Metal:** Also known as "Cross Platform Look And Feel" or "Ocean theme". The typical Java look - this is the default. This class is part of the Java Runtime as `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`.
- **Nimbus:** A modern Synth-based laf. This class is part of the Java Runtime 6u10 as `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`.
- **Native:** Also known as "System Look And Feel". These classes are part of the Java Runtime as `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` (MS Windows), or `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel` (Linux), or `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.mac.MacLookAndFeel` (Mac OS) depending on the operating system you use (See also `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`).
- **Motif:** A classic laf. This class is part of the Java Runtime as `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel`.
- ... or choose a third-party laf such as Substance, Napkin, Synthetica, TinyLaF, JGoodies Plastic, and many more. Note that NetBeans is not being regularly tested with alternate/third-party look and feel implementations. Various implementations may or may not work well.

#### To use the themes

1. Decide which Look and Feel widget you want (see list above) and remember it's class name ().
2. If it's a third-party widget, download the JAR file containing the custom laf classes ().
3. Start NetBeans from the command line with the following options (cf. examples below):
4. If it's a third-party widget, place the JAR in the classpath using the `--cp:p <jar_path>` start-up option.
5. Select the laf using the `--laf <laf_class>` start-up option.
   When NetBeans starts you should notice the different look. If not, check for typos.
6. If you like the theme, make your custom start-up parameters permanent.